# Count occurrence in 2D array and put custom formula result in the end of array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 2D array from a google spreadsheet for example:-

[image]

Please Note that the length and width of the 2D array can be of any size. However, the count will always begin with second col1.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxUOI');
var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var lastR = sh.getLastRow()
var data = sh.getRange("A4:QC"+lastR).getValues();
```

`data` Array looks like `[[alpha,a,a,b,c],[beeta,b,b,a,a],[gama,a,b,c,c],[alpha,d,c,a,a]]`

Now I want to count the occurrence of element from each row and push the formula `result` at the end of every column.

If My formula is `(a+c)/(b+d)`

From the above example the results are

```
(2+1)/(1+0) = 3  //occurrence in 1st row a=2,b=1,c=1,d=0
(2+0)/(2+0) = 1  //occurrence in 2nd row a=2,b=2,c=0,d=0
(1+2)/(1+0) = 3  //occurrence in 3rd row a=1,b=1,c=2,d=0
(2+1)/(0+1) = 3  //occurrence in 4th row a=2,b=0,c=1,d=1
```

Now the result should be at the end of the array

```
[[alpha,a,a,b,c,3],[beeta,b,b,a,a,1],[gama,a,b,c,c,3],[alpha,d,c,a,a,3]]
```

Comment: What do you want to do if `(b + d)` is `0` (if anything, unless `Infinity` is acceptable there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a counting function which uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to count the occurrences of each element in the sub-array. Then, create another function which uses the results of the count to calculate the value according to the formula and then pushes it to the sub-array. Finally, apply this function to each element of your overall array (in this case, it is done in-place but this could also be accomplished by creating a new array and using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```js
const count = (list, els) => {
  const acc = {};
  els.forEach(el => { acc[el] = 0; });
  return list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr]++;
    return acc;
  }, acc);
};

const formula = list => {
  const { a, b, c, d } = count(list, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
  const x = (a + c) / (b + d);
  list.push(x);
};

const data = [['alpha', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['beeta', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], ['gama', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], ['x-ray', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a']];
data.forEach(formula);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Its not working for large data some how I am unable to get the result. Your code works fine but I am unable to understand what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Strangely I realized instead of `a,b,c,d` My actual Values are `S2/F,S1/F,S3/F,MSF` which this code is unable to read. what could be the workaround

Comment: @Mask can you explain a little more about what you mean? Maybe with some examples of exactly what you're doing so I can understand where it's going wrong

Comment: I removed spechial character "/" from my array and then applied your code. It works fine now.